# Loop recursive inside a folder using Emscripten File API

Tags: javascript, node.js, emscripten

How to loop files inside a folder using Emscripten?

E.g., I've created data a folder `'/res'` (`FS.mkdir('/res')`) and some data temp files and subfolders inside the `'/res'`.

How can I loop files and folders inside?

I've just found `FS.isDir()`. but no more.
What is the proper way to extract the data (file names):

```
/res/file1.txt
/res/file2.txt
/res/file2.txt
/res/dir/file01.txt
/res/dir/file02.txt
```

etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FS.readdir` lists all names (files and folders) of a directory, but not recursively. You can use `FS.lookupPath`, `FS.isFile` and `FS.isDir` to recursively crawl the filesystem.

```js
function fsReadAllFiles(folder) {
  const files = [];

  function impl(curFolder) {
    for (const name of FS.readdir(curFolder)) {
      if (name === '.' || name === '..') continue;

      const path = `${curFolder}/${name}`;
      const { mode, timestamp } = FS.lookupPath(path).node;
      if (FS.isFile(mode)) {
        files.push({path, timestamp});
      } else if (FS.isDir(mode)) {
        impl(path);
      }
    }
  }

  impl(folder);
  return files;
}
```

Note, this probably breaks for symlinks, but that should be a simple addition.

Answer (score -1):

`FS.readdir()` returns childs of directory.

Comment: why did you accept this answer? readdir does not return the children of subdirectories.

Comment: @ConnorClark I'm sorry. I don't remember

Comment: No worries, I've provided a function that works for me as an answer.

Comment: As of May 2022, FS doesn't have `readdir` function.

Comment: @VladimirObrizan I've changed accepted answer. Thanks